# Changing mouse-cursor

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse-cursor

I have seen in some applications the cursor changing. How do you do that? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you only need default system cursors (arrow, button, hand and I-beam) its better to use this:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/MouseCursor.html

Comment: Looks like this might be an up-to-date link to that document: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/MouseCursor.html